Webhook notification for new app version in Apple App Store and Google Play Store?
I'm developing a mobile app and I'd like to be automatically notified when a new version is available on the Apple App Store and Google Play Store. Is there a way to register a webhook with either platform that would be triggered whenever a new version is released?
Ideally, the webhook would provide details about the new version, such as version number and any release notes.
I could not find anything on Google to answer this yes/no question, so I'm hoping to get some more insight here.
Thanks!

Any update on this?
